# Not able to install gazebo2 using Oracle VM

Tags: ros

I tried to follow the following steps during `gazebo2` installation using the documentation of `Gazebo2`

- Indigo is using the `gazebo 2.x` series, start by installing it:

  `sudo apt-get install -y gazebo2`
- Getting error in this commad:

  > E: Unable to locate package
- Download the source code from the gazebo_ros_pkgs github repository:

  cd ~/catkin_ws/src
  git clone https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs.git -b indigo-devel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These instructions are taken from the gazebo installation guide [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=install_ubuntu&cat=install), take a look before proceeding :

**Gazebo2 : Step by step installation :**

1 - Setup your computer to accept software from packages.osrfoundation.org.

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable `lsb_release -cs` main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list'
```

2 - Setup keys :

```
$ wget http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

3 - Install Gazebo.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install gazebo2
```

4 - Check your installation

```
$ gazebo
```

**Gazebo pkgs for ROS Indigo :**

run the following command :

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-pkgs ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-control
```

or to install all gazebo ros pkgs :

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo-*
```

Note : depending on the ROS version, pick the right gazebo version following this [guide](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_wrapper_versions).

Cheers,

Comment: followed the above steps in VM, doesn't work. should I setup dual boot ??